# Xamarin forms: tooltip in windows app

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, tooltip, xamarin.uwp

I am building an app using Xamarin forms PCL. My app will work on android, ios, windows 10 and windows 8.1.

I need to implement a tooltip control on tap event for windows os only. I tried [tooltip](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip/) like this-

```
if(Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Windows)
{
    var tapGestureRecognizer1 = new TapGestureRecognizer();
    tapGestureRecognizer1.Tapped += TapGestureRecognizer1_Tapped1;
    icon1.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer1);
}

private void TapGestureRecognizer1_Tapped1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Constant.UserActiveTime = DateTime.Now;
    Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ToolTip toolTip1 = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ToolTip();
    toolTip1.Content = "Hi";
    toolTip1.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;    
}
```

Is there any working sample for tooltip control or any nuget package?

Comment: Can you clarify what's not working?

Comment: @Sefe Nothing is working. No tooltip appears.

Comment: You are creating a tooltip but you are not attaching it to anything. No wonder you don't see it. Check your tooltip's `Parent` property. If it is `null`, don't be surprised your tooltip doesn't show.

Comment: @Sefe how can I add its parent.

Comment: You should do your own research first. Good places to start would be [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.tooltip.aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.tooltipservice.aspx). These references took me less time to find than it took you to write the question.

Comment: @Sefe I tried ` Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ToolTipService.SetToolTip(img, toolTip1);` it shows cannot convert image to dependency object

Comment: This icon1 is xaml image control

Comment: @Sefe any idea I am coding all this in class file of my xaml page in pcl project.

Comment: try toolTip1.SetToolTip(control,"....")

Comment: @MikeMa I tried `toolTip.SetToolTip(icon1, toolTip);`  but it says Tooltip does not contain definition for SetToolTip

Comment: @Sonali  [Here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/46646/best-way-to-display-a-floating-tooltip) is the third party library for displaying tooltips . Xamarin forms pcl did not do the tooltips render. I am trying to use the dependency  service to show the tooltips but meet some issues.

Answer (score 4):

Here is solution which I implemented for Xamarin UWP app.

Created custom stacklayout because I wanted a tooltip on whole section.In that you can add different controls.
Main part is I'm using ClassId to get what text is needed to display in tooltip, you can add your custom property if you wish.

Hope it helps :-)

Added custom StackLayout :

```
public class ToolTipStacklayout :StackLayout
{
}
```

Added renderer in UWP :

```
public class ToolTipRendererUWP : VisualElementRenderer<StackLayout, StackPanel>
{

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<StackLayout> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Element == null)
            return;            

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Element.ClassId))
        {
            ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip();
            toolTip.Content = Element.ClassId;
            ToolTipService.SetToolTip(this, toolTip);
        }         
    }}
```

Also came to implement this for MAC desktop application .

Here is the solution for MAC :

```
 public class ToolTipRendererMAC : VisualElementRenderer<StackLayout>
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<StackLayout> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Element == null)
            return;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Element.ClassId))
            this.ToolTip = Element.ClassId;

    }}
```