# Xamarin forms UWP tooltips

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp

I would like to add tooltips in Xamarin for UWP by using a native view and the Windows.UI.Xaml Nuget package. I have added the following reference to the xaml page to get the windows native view:

```
<ContentPage 

             xmlns:win="clr-namespace:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;assembly=Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime;targetPlatform=Windows"   

</ContentPage>
```

I can successfully access native windows controls, e.g. a TextBlock:

```
<    win: TextBlock Text="S"/>
```

However, when I try to add the tooltip to the control:

```
<win:TextBlock Text="S" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Service agreement"/>
```

I get the following exception during compilation:

> "Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: 'Position 56:45. Type
>   ToolTipService not found in xmlns
>   http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms'"

Is the system getting confused between the standard Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls namespace and the extended one from the Nuget package?

Comment: I search some info, but I can not find any way to add ToolTips for native view in Forms, if you want to achieve this , I suggest you can custom render for any control that you want to display ToolTips, this is one same thread that you can take a look:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41978916/xamarin-forms-tooltip-in-windows-app

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT: Thank you. Do you recommend that I customize an entry, as explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/entry? Or is there a TextBox-specific renderer in UWP that I should use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ToolTipService` is attached property, and it will not find ToolTipService assembly in Forms client, the better way is use [`Effect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/creating) to create your own tip service and render it in UWP platform. You could refer the following steps.

- > Create a subclass of the PlatformEffect class.
- > Override the OnAttached method and write logic to customize the control.
- > Override the OnDetached method and write logic to clean up the control customization, if required.
- > Add a **ResolutionGroupName** attribute to the effect class. This attribute sets a company wide namespace for effects, preventing collisions with other effects with the same name. Note that this attribute can only be applied once per project.
- > Add an ExportEffect attribute to the effect class. This attribute registers the effect with a unique ID that's used by Xamarin.Forms, along with the group name, to locate the effect prior to applying it to a control. The attribute takes two parameters – the type name of the effect, and a unique string that will be used to locate the effect prior to applying it to a control.

**UWP Code Part**

```
[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("Microsoft")]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(UWPToolTipEffect), nameof(TooltipEffect))]

namespace NativeSwitch.UWP
{
    public class UWPToolTipEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            var control = Control ?? Container;

            if (control is DependencyObject)
            {
                ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip();
                toolTip.Content = TooltipEffect.GetText(Element);
                switch (TooltipEffect.GetPosition(Element))
                {
                    case TooltipPosition.Bottom:
                        toolTip.Placement = Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Bottom;
                        break;
                    case TooltipPosition.Top:
                        toolTip.Placement = Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Top;
                        break;
                    case TooltipPosition.Left:
                        toolTip.Placement = Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Left;
                        break;
                    case TooltipPosition.Right:
                        toolTip.Placement = Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Right;
                        break;
                    default:
                        return;
                }
                ToolTipService.SetToolTip(control, toolTip);
            }

        }

        protected override void OnDetached()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**Forms code part**

```
public static class TooltipEffect
{

    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty =
      BindableProperty.CreateAttached("Text", typeof(string), typeof(TooltipEffect), string.Empty, propertyChanged: OnTextChanged);

    public static readonly BindableProperty PositionProperty =
      BindableProperty.CreateAttached("Position", typeof(TooltipPosition), typeof(TooltipEffect), TooltipPosition.Bottom);


    public static string GetText(BindableObject view)
    {
        return (string)view.GetValue(TextProperty);
    }

    public static void SetText(BindableObject view, string value)
    {
        view.SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }

    public static TooltipPosition GetPosition(BindableObject view)
    {
        return (TooltipPosition)view.GetValue(PositionProperty);
    }

    public static void SetPosition(BindableObject view, TooltipPosition value)
    {
        view.SetValue(PositionProperty, value);
    }

    static void OnTextChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var view = bindable as View;
        if (view == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        string text = (string)newValue;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            view.Effects.Add(new ControlTooltipEffect());
        }
        else
        {
            var toRemove = view.Effects.FirstOrDefault(e => e is ControlTooltipEffect);
            if (toRemove != null)
            {
                view.Effects.Remove(toRemove);
            }
        }
    }

}

public enum TooltipPosition
{
    Bottom,

    Right,

    Left,

    Top
}

class ControlTooltipEffect : RoutingEffect
{
    public ControlTooltipEffect() : base($"Microsoft.{nameof(TooltipEffect)}")
    {

    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
// forms project namesapce
xmlns:effects="clr-namespace:ToolTipTestApp"
......

<win:TextBlock
    effects:TooltipEffect.Position="Right"
    effects:TooltipEffect.Text="Hello"
    Text="Hello Wrold"
    />
```

Comment: How to support multi line tool tip in the above example?